# Drawing on lots of canvas elements without losing responsiveness

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am drawing on a lot of canvas elements one after the other. The functions are computationally expensive. If there are 15 canvas elements, the page doesn't show anything until all the canvas drawings have finished. This results in people getting messages on their browser about the script taking too long to execute. Also during this process the page remains unresponsive.

I want suggestions on how to solve the following 2 problems -

1) I want to show a canvas as soon as it is completely drawn. I don't want the user to wait for drawings to finish on 15 canvas elements.

2) I want to make the page responsive while the computation is happening.

Comment: what could take so much time ?

Comment: Exactly what @GameAlchemist has said, the canvas element itself isn't causing the issue, its whatever you're doing code wise (drawing something I assume) that's causing the issue.

Comment: Ditto & Ditto, we need to see your code to help you.

Comment: +1 show meee the code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I figured out the obvious problem. Javascript is single threaded and I am drawing on my canvases one after the other without any gap. This keeps the browser busy computing the coordinates and it updates the page only after all the computation has happened. To solve the problem, I created a function to draw only on one canvas at a time. This function in turn uses setTimeout to call itself after 250 ms. This way the browser gets time between two consecutive canvas drawings to update the recently drawn canvas. The page also remains responsive this way.

Comment: Dude, wtf are you drawing? Google maps?

Comment: @MattHarrison Actually I am generating lots of fractals. Some of them can have upto a million points. I wish I could make my own version of Google map. That would be cool!

Comment: Have you considered using requestAnimationFrame instead of setTimeout? The exact time between frames can vary somewhat, but it's usually a lot less than 250ms, so the result should be even more responsive.